# Syncing a file system that has no file on it

Tags: linux, filesystems, synchronization

Say I want to synchronize data buffers of a file system to disk (in my case the one of an USB stick partition) on a linux box.

While searching for a function to do that I found the following

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   sync()  causes  all buffered modifications to file metadata and 
>           data to be written to the underlying file sys‐
>           tems.
>
>   syncfs(int fd) is like sync(), but synchronizes just the file system 
>                  containing file referred to by  the  open  file
>                  descriptor fd.
> ```

But what if the file system has no file on it that I can open and pass to `syncfs`? Can I "abuse" the dot file? Does it appear on all file systems?

Is there another function that does what I want? Perhaps by providing a device file with major / minor numbers or some such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think you can do that. The root directory of your file system will have at least one inode for your root directory. You can use the .-file to do that. Play also around with ls -i to see the inode numbers.

Is there a possibility to avoid your problem by mounting your file system with sync? Does performance issues hamper? Did you have a look at remounting? This can sync your file system as well in particular cases.

I do not know what your application is, but I suffered problems with synchronization of files to a USB stick with the FAT32-file system. It resulted in weird read and write errors. I can not imagine any other valid reason why you should sync an empty file system.

Answer (score 0):

From man 8 sync description:

```
   "sync  writes  any  data  buffered  in  memory  out to disk.  This can include (but is not
   limited to) modified superblocks, modified inodes, and delayed reads and writes.  This 
   must be implemented by the kernel; The  sync program does nothing but exercise the sync(2)
   system call."
```

So, note that it's all about *modification* (modified inode, superblocks etc). If you don't have any modification, it don't have anything to sync up.

Comment: Well, I guess that wasn't the question. But just to answer your question, sync writes back all the dirty buffers to disk and also updates superblock/inode metadata info. ANd, sync is something which always successful, so if you delete files this info will needs to be updated too. So, will be synced. If you don't call sync manually, it'll get synced up by the kernel flasher thread.

Comment: I dont wanna use sync because i dont want to sync all filesystems. Only one particular.

Comment: You perhaps need something like fdatasync() or fsync(). But, one thing you need to understand whether you want sync or not whether you call fsync/sync or not, a kernel thread is running and dedicate for these particular job. And what sync/fsync does is runs the kernel flasher thread by force that does the rest. This kernel thread runs periodically and configurable via /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs tuning.